# Trendnet tew-828dru with Comcast, no WAN IP/Connectivity

Tags: dd-wrt

I installed the latest version of DD-WRT on my tew-828dru, and am unable to get a connection. It doesn't get a WAN IP at all. I have Comcast, and have tried things like cloning the MAC address of the router, the MAC address of my laptop, etc. to no avail. Also, the wl0 interface (for the 5ghz) has a mac of all 0's, and the radio is listed as being off, and I can't find any way to turn it on. I've been trying all kinds of things to get this stuff to work, but I keep running into walls.

Comment: Did you try calling comcast?

Comment: Yeah, they didn't have anything useful to say, haha. They said from their end all looked well and the router should work if plugged in to the modem, which it does when I don't have dd-wrt on there.

Comment: Have you power-cycled your modem?